# Получение ответа от сом порта

Tags: c#

Настраиваю порт, отправляю запрос. Для обработки ответа использую событие data received. Проблема в том, что ответ приходит не корректный, либо не полный, либо его совсем нет.  В чем причина?  Без события приходит корректный ответ с таймером в 30-50 мск. А Если использовать событие то ответ не полный.

```
public void SendRequestPort_K()
{    
    if (portKDD.IsOpen)
    {                  
         threadK = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(_WritePortK));
         portKDD.DiscardInBuffer();
         portKDD.DiscardInBuffer();
         portKDD.DataReceived += 
         new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(portKDD_DataReceived);
         threadK.Start(_numberK);
         while (!threadK.IsAlive) ;
    }
}

public void SetSettingPort()
{       
    portKDD = new SerialPort();
    portKDD.PortName = "COM3";
    portKDD.BaudRate = 19200;
    portKDD.DataBits = 8;
    portKDD.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    portKDD.Parity = Parity.None;
    portKDD.StopBits = StopBits.One;
}

private void _WritePortK(object _numberK)
{       
    portKDD.DiscardInBuffer();
    portKDD.DiscardOutBuffer();  
    int numberK = Int32.Parse(_numberK.ToString());
    int lengthByte = 0;
    Request Request = new Request();
    Request.CreatePack_0x03_0х04("000", K[numberK], 0 , 0x04, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 }, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x02 }); //формирую запрос
    portKDD.Write(Request.pack.ToArray(), 0, 
    Request.pack.ToArray().Length);// идет запрос 1 4 0 0 0 2 crc1 crc2
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    //int flag = portKDD.BytesToRead; 
    //if (flag != 0)
    //{    
           byte[] _bytes = new byte[100];
           lengthByte = portKDD.Read(_bytes, 0, 100);
    //}
    numberK++;
    if(number<31)
        _WritePortK(numberK)
    else    
        threadK.Abort();
}

void portKDD_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{      
     //int flag = portKDD.BytesToRead; 
     //if (flag != 0)
     //{
           //byte[] _bytes = new byte[100];
           //lengthByte = portKDD.Read(_bytes, 0, 100);
     //}
     //portKDD.DiscardInBuffer();
     //portKDD.DiscardInBuffer();
}
```

Comment: добавь код который  исползуешь

Comment: Потому что никто не обещает по COM-порту "полный" ответ. Потому что понятия "полный" в этом способе нет.

Comment: Для этого обычно в начале сообщения говориться его длинна и ожидается его полный приход в цикле. После этого обрабатывается полное сообщение. Это как TCP протокол, там тоже может сразу не прийти, или не прийти вовсе. А вот по поводу некорректности, это что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Vardan Vardanyan  Выложил код

Comment: @Дмитрий Чистик А как это сделать в  цикле? По байтно? Если так то я уже пробовал. Программа зависала.

Comment: @Дмитрий Чистик Про корректность пока забудем

Comment: Как сделано у меня на примере TCPIP, в цикле
**1.** Получаю первые 4 байта (длинна пакета) **2.** Получаю все остальные байты. **3.** Получил все? разбираю пакет, переходим к п1, иначе к п2. Это все при условии что первые 4 байта пакета это длинна!

Comment: Я бы советовал обратиться к инструкции устройства, а именно как формируется пакет(сообщение) на нём. Написать формат пакета тут, а потом уже требовать примеры решения.

Comment: Извините, а у вас код в рабочем проекте вот именно так отформатирован? Подобную вольность в отношении разбиения на строки я в последний раз видел у Маяковского.

Comment: @VladD Я убрал все лишнее с кода.

Comment: @Дмитрий Чистик Использую обычный Modbas RTU протокол.

Comment: @VictorSayapov: Ну в любом случае второй и третий комментарии правильные: вы не должны рассчитывать, что `DataReceived` принесёт вам _все_ данные одним куском. Лучше отказаться от `DataReceived` вовсе и использовать чтение из `portKDD.BaseStream`

Answer (score 0):

Свойство SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold

Возвращает или задает число байтов во внутреннем входном буфере до возникновения события DataReceived.

Но лучше вообще отказаться от этого события всеми правдами и неправдами. Особенно если у вас есть какие либо служебные последовательности для разделения сообщений